# How to inspect the current Named Route using Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

according to the [Laravel 5.5 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes), there is a `named()` method for accessing route names:

```
if ($request->route()->named('profile')) {
    //
}
```

Inspecting the source, I learned that this `named` method simply fetches the 'as' property of the action object:

```
$this->action['as']
```

My problem is I'm stuck using Laravel 5.2, which doesn't have a `named()` method. I can't use `route()->action['as']` in my blade template, because the `action`object is protected. Is there an equivalent getter method in 5.2, to check the name of the current route? I want to flow control in my blade.php file like this:

```
@if(route()->action['as'] == 'blog.edit')
    //
@endif
```

Maybe I missed it, but I didn't see anything in the Laravel 5.2 docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

I succeeded in checking the route using

```
@if(request()->is('blog/add'))
    //
@endif
```

But that is using the route URI. I prefer to use the route name instead as it's less clunky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from Gitter courtesy of Ben Johnson:

```
@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'blog.edit')
    //
@endif
```